# rewrite all the requests to default.php except the request for sitemap.xml

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using htaccess to rewrite every request to default.php file.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^  blog/default.php
```

But I want to submit sitemap file of my website(sitemap.xml).So that request to `http://example.com/sitemap.xml rewrites to ->  blog/sitemap.xml.`

My unsuccessful try->

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml  blog/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^  blog/default.php
```

My htaccess rules are obviously not hardened. But I am new to this.Please help.

Comment: `Redirect 301 /sitemap.xml /blog/sitemap.xml`?

Comment: What if you put the sitemap rewrite at the end, what does it do for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use RewriteBase to reduce path to the blog directory. Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On # enable rewrite engine   
RewriteBase /blog/ # Set path "./blog" as a root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Excludes existed files from rewrite
RewriteCond $1 !^(default\.php|sitemap\.xml) # Setup $1 variable
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ default.php/$1 [L] # Process request params to default.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules are fine so far, although I guess, you get a rewrite loop. To avoid the loop, you can prefix the rules with a rewrite condition, which skips the rule when the requesst is for a real file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /blog/sitemap.xml [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /blog/default.php [L]
```